# How to pipe a stream after asynchronous calls without losing data?

Tags: node.js, stream

In my application I would like to be able to perform the following steps:

1. Obtain a read stream;
2. Wait for an asynchronous function to complete;
3. Pipe the stream to destination1;
4. Wait until another asynchronous function finishes;
5. Pipe destination1 to destination2.

I expect the following:

1. Stream processing only begins after step #5
2. Data is not lost
3. The whole logic fully resolves when the stream processing is over (`.on("finish")`).

Before any questions are asked, here's a code example:

```js
return new Promise(resolve => {
    logger.debug("Creating a stream");
    const stream = fs.createReadStream("/home/username/dev/resources/ex.tar.bz2");

    setTimeout(() => {
        logger.debug("Attaching pipe 1");
        const pipe1 = stream.pipe(
            through(
                function(data) {
                    logger.info("DATA in PIPE 1");
                    this.queue(data);
                },
                function() {
                    logger.info("END in PIPE 1");
                    this.queue(null);
                }
            )
        );

        stream.pause(); // LINE 1

        setTimeout(() => {
            logger.debug("Attaching pipe 2");
            const pipe2 = pipe1.pipe(
                through(
                    function() {
                        logger.info("DATA in PIPE 2");
                    },
                    function() {
                        logger.info("END in PIPE 2");
                        resolve();
                    }
                )
            )

            pipe2.resume(); // LINE 2
        }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
});
```

In this code, if both LINE 1 and LINE 2 are removed, the code does not work (prints **DATA in PIPE 1** and **END in PIPE 1**, never resolves) because:

- attaching destination 1 starts the flow of data;
- if I understand it correctly, by the time destination 2 is attached, the data has been consumed.

If both LINE 1 and LINE 2 are present, the code *appears* to work (prints **DATA in PIPE 1**, **DATA in PIPE 2**, **END in PIPE 1**, **END in PIPE 2** and resolves) since:

- LINE 1 stops the data flow from `stream`;
- attaching destination 2 (somewhat confusingly) does not start the flow from the original source;
- LINE 2 starts the data flow.

According to the NodeJS documentation:

> if there are piped destinations, then calling stream.pause() will not guarantee that the stream will remain paused once those destinations drain and ask for more data

Which leads me to my main question: **is it possible to *reliably* implement this exactly the way I am trying to (with async calls between pipes)?**

Bonus questions:

1. I guess that the right way to work with pipes may be to ensure that all the required asynchronous calls are complete before constructing the whole pipeline all at once. **Is my guess correct?**
2. **Why is it so that attaching destination 2 does not trigger the flow, whereas attaching destination 1 does?**
3. If I replace LINE 2 with either `pipe1.resume()` or `stream.resume()`, the code works equally well. I guess this extends to an unlimited number of pipes. **Why can I resume the original flow by calling `.resume()` on *any* of the pipes? How is this resume different from the one that is supposed to happen during pipe attachment (which apparently does not work the same way)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are experiencing the *node stream variant* of [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) - the act of observing the stream changes the behavior of the stream.

Before doing anything else, remove the implementation of the `through` Stream (although very simple, this in itself can influence the behavior). Let's use built-in `Passthrough` streams, which we know have no side effects:

```
logger.debug("Attaching pipe 1");
const pipe1 = new PassThrough();
stream.pipe(pipe1);
pipe1.on('data', data => logger.info('DATA in PIPE 1')); 
pipe1.on('end', () => logger.info('END in PIPE 1')); 


// ...

logger.debug("Attaching pipe 2");
const pipe2 = new PassThrough();
pipe1.pipe(pipe2);
pipe2.on('data', data => logger.info('DATA in PIPE 2')); 
pipe2.on('end', () => {
    logger.info('END in PIPE 2');
    resolve();
});
```

Output:

```
Creating a stream
Attaching pipe 1
DATA in PIPE 1
END in PIPE 1
Attaching pipe 2
END in PIPE 2
```

So, with no pause/resume statements, this works (it shouldn't hang forever, I'm not sure why you're seeing that behavior); however, there is *no data* in pipe2. And it certainly didn't wait around or buffer anything.

The issue is that by attaching an `on('data')` handler (which is something that `through` also does), you are informing the stream that it has a way to consume data - it does not need to buffer anything. When we add the pipe to `pipe2`, it *does* start piping immediately - there's just no data left to pipe, because we already consumed it.

Try *commenting out* the `data` handler for `pipe1`:

```
//pipe1.on('data', data => logger.info('DATA in PIPE 1'));
```

Now we get exactly what we'd expect:

```
Creating a stream
Attaching pipe 1
Attaching pipe 2
DATA in PIPE 2
END in PIPE 1
END in PIPE 2
```

Now, when we create the read stream, it immediately starts reading (into the buffer); we attach `pipe1`, which immediately begins piping data (into `pipe1`'s internal buffer); then we attach `pipe2`, which immediately begins piping data (into `pipe2`'s internal buffer). You could continue this indefinitely, eventually piping into a write stream and pumping the data to disk or into an HTTP response, etc.

Comment: Are you saying that as long as I pipe into properly implemented Duplex/Transform streams, I will not lose any data, even if there are asynchronous calls between calls to `.pipe()`? And only when I attach a `data` handler, or perhaps a Writable pipe at the end of the chain, does the stream start draining (hope I use the correct term here)?

Comment: Yes to the first; asynchronous calls between pipe calls are fine.  Note that just adding pipes will immediately start _reading_ and filling internal buffers, unless readable is paused.  Once you add a data handler anywhere in chain or pipe into a writable, then you'll see standard write/drain behavior.

Comment: So a transformation library which uses `through` internally is not really a properly implemented one, since if I pipe into it, I can expect to run into this problem, right? I guess that explains everything that I need to know, thanks : ]

Comment: I don't want to bag on `through`, but I think that's where the blame is here - it assumes your destination is already set up when you pipe.  Note that `through` was deprecated many years ago in favor of successor https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2, which does not have this problem (just tried converting your example to through2 and it worked like a charm).